# Error with iterator in the view haml ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to make a list where each element of it shows the name of op.variant.tipoVariant

```
%h3.section-header.title-size.bold Variantes(test):
%input{list: 'variants'}
%datelist#variants
  -@product.options_products.each do |op|
    #this line have a problem
    %option{value: op.variant.tipoVariant}
```

Comment: Can you add the error message that you see when this has a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because I type datElist and is datAlist

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
%option{value: op.try(:variant).try(:tipoVariant)}
```

May be you get Nil error.

Please refer http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try